# getItem localstorage containing a string

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have multiple keys in my localstorage: `task-1,task-2, task-3 ...` I'm searching a way to get the total of the keys starting with the string "tasks-" in order to place it in my loop instead of `localStorage.length`.

In fact if I have an other app that uses the localstorage, my loop returns me a length corresponding to ALL the keys in the localStorage, including the ones that are out of the app in question.

```
   i=0;

   if(localStorage.getItem("task-"+i) != null){

     for( i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){ 

       console.log(i)

     }
  }
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you control the creation of these items, it would make much more sense to store them in an object and use JSON to convert between object and string:

```
var tasksObject = {
    task1: ...,
    task2: ...,
    ...
};

window.localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasksObject));

... later ...

var tasks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

for (var task in tasks) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements should be switched. Loop over everything and see if each item matches your condition.

```
var count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){ 
    if(localStorage.getItem("task-"+i) != null){
        console.log(i)
        count++;
    }
}
// count contains number of items beginning with task
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, e, tasks=[];
for (i=0; (e=localStorage["task-"+i])!==undefined; i++) {
   console.log(e);
   tasks.push(e);
}
```

And how about

```
localStorage['num-tasks'] = tasks.length;
```